# JS - Export array from one file to another

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I have the following array on a .js file:

```
//file name: myVar.js
    var myVar= [
    {id:1, items:
    [
        {
            "Name": "John",
            "Surname": "Doe",
            "Country": "Portugal"
        }
    ]},
   {id:2, items:
    [
        {
            "Name": "Mary",
            "Surname": "Jane",
            "Country": "France"
        }
     ]
  }
]
```

What I want to do is to, call it in another .js file for example:

```
//file name: expVar.js
var expVar = //var exported
```

I've tried a few things I've found through internet bue none have seemed to work. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many modern browsers support [JavaScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules), which you could use to `export` your array from one file and `import` it in another.

It would look something like this:

```
// myVar.js
export var myVar = [/* your content */];
```

And in your second file:

```
// expVar.js
import { myVar } from './myVar.js'

// Now you can use `myVar` here directly!
console.log(myVar);
```

P.S.: Often times, you would have some kind of bundler (e.g. [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org) or [Parcel](https://parceljs.org)) that assembles different JavaScript files for you. They might support different kinds of modules (e.g. `require`) but the JavaScript modules are among the most common ones.

Comment: That was indeed working until I started adding functions to the file where the var was imported. Can you explain why? I want to use the imported var in my function and the error is "function is declared but never read" as it is read in an HTML file and if I delete the import command it works fine.

Comment: Hm, that sounds like your editor/linter setup is not aware of how you are using/consuming your functions. If everything works as expected (aside from that “false positive” error message ), you might want to look into re-configuring your editor/linter to not complain about these types of errors. At least this would be my first hunch without knowing more about your exact setup/files.

Answer (score 0):

Just using export keyword

```
export var expVar
```

And import expVar in other file